# How to check JSON field when send field not match with expect JSON in wiremock?

Tags: json, wiremock

I have some question about checking Wiremock again

I want to check JSON all field

{"petType" : 1, "wildLevel": 40,"petStatus": 1}

If I send invalid field such as

{"petType" : 1, "wildLevel": 40,"patStatus": 1}

{"catType" : 1, "wildLevel": 40,"patStatus": 1}

{"petType" : 1, "wildLevelxx": 40,"patStatus": 1}

, it should show invalid request.

This mapping JSON that I can write

```
{
    "mappings":[
        {
            "priority":1,
            "request":{
                "method":"PATCH",
                "urlPath":"/pet/status",
                "bodyPatterns":[
                    {
                        "or":[
                            
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "response":{
                "status":400,
                "transformers":[
                    "response-template"
                ],
                "bodyFileName":"invalid-request.json",
                "headers":{
                    "Content-Type":"application/json"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "priority":2,
            "request":{
                "method":"PATCH",
                "urlPath":"/pet/status",
                "bodyPatterns":[
                    {
                        "and":[
                            {
                                "matchesJsonPath":"$[?(@.petType == '404040')]"
                            },
                            {
                                "matchesJsonPath":"$.wildLevel "
                            },
                            {
                                "matchesJsonPath":"$.petStatus "
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "response":{
                "status":200,
                "transformers":[
                    "response-template"
                ],
                "bodyFileName":"find-success.json",
                "headers":{
                    "Content-Type":"application/json"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "priority":3,
            "request":{
                "method":"PATCH",
                "urlPath":"/pet/status",
                "bodyPatterns":[
                    {
                        "and":[
                            {
                                "matchesJsonPath":"$.petType "
                            },
                            {
                                "matchesJsonPath":"$.wildLevel "
                            },
                            {
                                "matchesJsonPath":"$.petStatus "
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "response":{
                "status":403,
                "transformers":[
                    "response-template"
                ],
                "bodyFileName":"data-not-found.json",
                "headers":{
                    "Content-Type":"application/json"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now , I have no idea to find solution , plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your request body will only ever contain those three fields, you can use a combination of:

- `equalToJson`
- `ignoreExtraElements = false`
- `json-Unit Placeholder`

All of the information on those can be [found on this page](http://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/#json-equality).

The solution would look something like...

```
...
"bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "equalToJson": "{ \"petType\": \"${json-unit.any-number}\", \"wildLevel\": \"${json-unit.any-number}\", \"petStatus\": \"${json-unit.any-number}\" }",
        "ignoreExtraElements": false
      }
    ]
...
```

We're checking here that the request body contains all three of those fields (petType, wildLevel, and petStatus), and only contains those fields, and all of those fields' values are numbers. If those conditions are not met, then this will not be considered a match. I would set this as the higher priority (1), and have a more general "not matched" mapping for the cases where this mapping is not matched, where you return the error.